# Is there a rule of thumb for converting Global References per second to IOPS?

Tags: intersystems-cache, san

working on sizing storage for a cache' database, I have an idea of the GREF/s but I need to convert it to IOPS?

Answer (score 1):

monitoring performance in [mgstat](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20121/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GCM_mgstat#GCM_C136212)
view columns
PhyRds - Physical reads from disk.
PhyWrs - Physical writes to disk.